# Laravel multiple joins in different tables

Tags: php, join, laravel-5, eloquent

I have these tables:
`Professor`, `Turma` and `Discipline`. (Turma = class).

I have another table called `professor_turma` which is a pivot between the relation of `professor` and `turma`. Inside this table I have some keys: `cod_professor`, `cod_turma`, `cod_discipline`.

For each row inside `professor_turma`, I need to bring the content of `Turma` table and also the name of the professor which is inside the `professor` table.

The thing is: I have only one relation and I can't change that. So I tried to work with `belongsToMany` but I can't get all the data I need. With the following code, I'm able to list all professor's name but I can't get the `Turma` they teache.

#### My Model

```
class Professor extends Model
{
    protected $table = "professor";
    protected $primaryKey = 'cod_professor';

    public function turmas()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Turma', 'professor_turma','cod_professor', 'cod_turma')->withPivot('CH','ano_semestre');
    }
}
```

#### My Controller

```
class ProfessorController extends Controller
{
    public function getProfessorList()
    {
        $professor = \App\Professor::all();
        return View::make('professor', compact('professor'));
    }
}
```

#### My View

```
<ul>
    @foreach($professor as $prof)
        <li>
            <h3 data-id="{{ $prof->cod_professor }}" class="prof-name">{{ $prof->cod_professor }} - {{ $prof->nome }}
                <input type="checkbox" name="" value="" class="check_prof" />
            </h3>

            @if(count($prof->turmas()->get()))
                <ul class="list-disc">
                    @foreach($prof->turmas as $disc)
                        <li data-dia="{{ $disc->dia_semana }}" data-time="{{ $disc->hr_inicio}}" data-id="{{ $disc->cod_disciplina }}">{{ $disc->nome_disciplina }}</li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            @endif
        </li>
    @endforeach
</ul>
```

I mannualy built a query and what I really need is something like this(I Really don't know how to specify joins like the ones in the query below):

```
SELECT DISTINCT professor.nome, professor_turma.cod_professor, professor_turma.cod_turma, professor_turma.cod_disciplina, turma.nome_disciplina
FROM professor_turma
INNER JOIN professor ON professor_turma.cod_professor = professor.cod_professor
INNER JOIN turma ON professor_turma.cod_turma = turma.cod_turma AND professor_turma.cod_disciplina = turma.cod_disciplina
WHERE professor_turma.cod_professor =  ?
```

Maybe create the model of `professor_turma` and from this one I make the joins??
How could I specify the joins?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using join keyword, you can use the 'with' keyword to get the related table values.

```
$professor = Professor::with('turmas', 'disciplines')->find($professorId);
```

where turmas and disciplines are the relationships set in Professor model.

Comment: And where does the `$professorId` would come from ? I'd like to loop through all of them and list them all plus show their `class/turma/` in case they have one or more.

Comment: What does it returns me? When I try to `dd( {{ $professor }})` I get a  `Builder`. How may I access the data correctly ??

Comment: If you want all the professors then

$professors = \App\Professor::with('turmas', 'disciplines')->get();

Then loop through each professor item.

Comment: It returns me every row from table `turma` that matches the `cod_professor.cod_turma` ... Would you know tell me how do I add another `inner join` clausule besides the one created with `belongsToMany` ?  Something like: `from table1 inner join table 2 on table1.id = table2.id AND table1.cod = table2.cod`. How may I add this `AND`?